# How to clear DNS cache in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, caching, dns, reverse-proxy

On Linux Debian 10 (Buster), I am using the http(s) client `google-chrome-stable`.

I was configuring (nginx) and testing (chrome) a reverse proxy and it got cached using a wrong domain.

I fixed the configuration but it still resolve to the wrong domain.

- I have tried to go `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and click on `Clear host cache` but that didn't change anything.
- I have tried to go `chrome://net-internals/#sockets` and click on `Flush socket pools` but that didn't change anything.

I am not working with FireFox, so FireFox can resolve correctly (so does `curl`).

After about 10 minutes, **without restarting chrome**. I did <kbd>F5</kbd> (refresh) and it was loading the proper page. I haven't found a manual way to immediatly clear chrome cache.

I am doing devops and I haven't solved this issue for years.

Would love to know how to do one day :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you open developer console F12 and then hold down on the refresh button and then select empty cache and hard reload?

Take a look at this [gif](https://gyazo.com/437949b749851c8afd8ab74c246ab2b1) for an example.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by `hold down on the refrehs button`, I don't see such button in the developer console. But I was able to check a checkbox `disable cache (while developer console is open)` and after refreshing, the page was correctly resolved. Not sure if this is what you meant. I am currently facing this error often so I'll take any advices that could help me solve this faster.

Comment: Hi there, Sorry for the slow reply.

I'm running on windows so this may not be the same on linux but if you take a look at [this](https://gyazo.com/437949b749851c8afd8ab74c246ab2b1) you can see that while I have the development console open holding down on the page refresh button I get an option to clear the cache

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that one! You should add the gif in the response.